# How not Sort the Class variable names in C# watch and visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Class with these variable names

the Problem is that when I watch the variable in the Watch, VS will automatically sort the variables by their name!
I juts wanted them to be appear as I defined them in the Class, with that order

Please see this Picture, it's easier to see that here

[image: See This Image]

Comment: Why dont you use a single `List<float>`? ;-)

Comment: There are lot's of none float type there, it's a partial part of the class variables

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but you can add all the watches you like one-by-one. E.g. stuff.DMTIIIE, stuff.DMTISE etc.

Comment: There is almost 1000 variable names there! it's not possible to add them by hand

Comment: @ASiDesigner: sure, you can'd add all fields into the same list, but those which belong to the same topic and have same datatypes. If the order is important dont rely on the order of class members, this order can always change or be refactored. If you have 1000 fields in this class this is clearly a design issue, use few collections like `List<T>`/`T[]` or a `Dictionary<string, T>`.

Comment: I have come with this solution, Just copy the variable names in a text file like this and copy and past into watch window
Something like this


    stuff.DMTI
    stuff.DMTII
    stuff.DMTIII
    stuff.DMTIE
    stuff.DMTIIE
    stuff.DMTIIIE
    stuff.DMTISE
    stuff.DMTIISE
    stuff.DMTIIISE
    stuff.DMTI2
    stuff.DMTV
    stuff.DMTVV
    stuff.DMTVVV
    stuff.DMTV2
    
    stuff. rms_I
    .....